# Could you please check out my answer and tell if there are any points I might be missing?

Tags: algorithms

Let $G(V, E)$ be an undirected connected finite graph with the weight
function $w$ : $E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$. It is known that the weights of the edges in E are all different. Can
$G$ have multiple different minimum spanning trees? Justify your answer (provide an example
or prove a converse).

My answer:
To prove converse, it is enough to provide one example where the statement will not hold, right?
[My example of a graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYk0O.png)

Comment: If the converse is: $G$ cannot have multiple different minimum spanning trees, an example is not enough because there could be another $G$ with multiple spanning trees. 
In general an example is never a proof.

Comment: Then I am stuck. Could you please suggest how should I solve it?

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't quite understand you. You said that an example is not a proof, right?

Comment: Yes. An example is not a proof. 
You can only use an example to show that a statement is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant in the solution. I think I phrased myself incorrectly. I meant that I made a statement that it is possible to have multiple different minimum-spanning trees with the given conditions. Then, I try to provide an example where this statement doesn't hold. I hope you understood what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interpret your question

> Can $G$ have multiple different minimum spanning trees? Justify your
> answer (provide an example or prove a converse)

the following way:

Statement I: Does there a $G$ exist with multiple different minimum spanning trees?

The converse would be

Statement II: There is no $G$ with multiple different minimum spanning trees.

Therefore an example is not enough to prove statement II because one has to check every possible graph $G$.

Comment: Thank you I think now I understand what is wrong with my logic.

Comment: How would you possibly approach it then?

Comment: I will not solve the problem for you. But you can try to find an example for a tree with multiple mininum spanning trees because that seems easier. If you fail, you can maybe see how to prove the statement, that it is not possible.

Comment: Sorry, I confused you. I didn't want you to solve the problem. Just was asking for the direction, which I got from you. Thank you. So, I will find an example fo such a graph and if it possible could you please check my answer?

Comment: Ok, yes I could do that.

Comment: I think I understood the solution. Should I apply the uniqueness property of the graph? I tried to draw some examples, but there exists only one MST.

Comment: Let's assume that there are 2 different minimum spanning trees like T1 and T2. They will not have the same edges, since w(e) is unique for every edge. Suppose, T1 has the smallest edge out of 2 MSTs, denote it as e1, and e2 will be the second smallest edge but from T2. Then, it implies that if we substitute e2 in T2 with e1 from T1, T2's total weight will decrease, which contradicts. with our initial proposition. Thus, we can have only 1 MST when the w(e) for all edges are unique. What do you think?

Comment: If you substitute e2 in T2 with e1 it might not be a MST anymore. 
But if have found here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/properties-of-minimum-spanning-tree-mst/ that your MST will be unique. So it is not possible to have two MSTs with the same weight.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#:~:text=graph%20is%20minimum.-,Uniqueness,have%20exactly%20the%20same%20cost here is a proof of the statement.

Comment: Is it possible for you to check my last proof for another exercise?

Comment: No, but feel free to post it into the forum.

Comment: ok. Thank you very much for your help.